# showing the mouse position coordinates in a dyanamic box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to accomplish the following:

As the mouse hovers in my webpage the current position coordinates should be displayed in small box alongside the pointer.

The small box will move along with the mouse.

I know how to get the current mouse coordinates using jquery.

Help me.

Answer (score 0):

getting the coordinates is the hard part, if you have that, just:

1. create a small `position:absolute;` div
2. write the coordinates into that div
3. set top/left to your coordinates
4. repeat 2/3 onmousemove

Comment: could you please elaborate. I am a newbie :(

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is have a div that is positioned absolute, with it's top and left are set as an offset to the 2 coordinates that the mouse has which update onmousemove. ( dont forget your z-index or your div may drop behind certain elements )